# Javascripts Conflicting Causing Undesirable Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple language learning site. The concept is you learn a series of 10 words flashcard style and then get quized on those same words using a variety of exercises. These exercises all utilize Javascript and when I add one particular script, audioControls.js, it causes some of the other exercises to have undesirable behavior (described below). When audioControls.js is commented out the undesirable behavior goes away, but it negates the functionality of the audio exercise.

The exercises I have so far are as follows:

1. Word Scramble
   [image]
2. Word Association
   [image]
3. Audio Association
   [image]
4. Spell Check

[image]

When include audioControls.js list of undesirable behavior:

-The drag and drop feature of the audio association and word association exercises quits working (drag and drop uses jquery)

-The next button no longer progresses to the next exercise (uses pagination)

-The tiles on the word scramble exercise are no longer sortable (sortable uses jquery)

**Note: When I click back to the homepage and then click back into the exercise the issues described above disappear, so I think this could be an issue of how the Javascripts are loading.**

When exclude audioControls.js:

-The issues described above disappear but you can no longer click the play button in the Audio Association exercise

audioControls.js:

```
$(function() {
  var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
  ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

  ctrl.onclick = function () {
    pause_html='<img src="/assets/playButton2.jpg" width="60" height="60">';
    play_html='<img src="/assets/playButton.jpg" width="60" height="60">';

    // Update the Button
    var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === pause_html;
    ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? play_html : pause_html;

    // Update the Audio
    var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
    yourAudio[method]();

    // Prevent Default Action
    return false;
  };

  document.getElementById('yourAudio').addEventListener('ended', function(){
    ctrl.innerHTML=play_html;
  });   
});
```

Audio Association html:

```
<h2>Audio Association <img src="/assets/informationTip.jpg" alt="Audio association exercise." title="Click the play button below to listen to the word. Drag the checkmark to its related answer in the blue box" width="35" height="25"></h2>


      <div class="well" style="background-color: #D8D8D8; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div>
          <audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
            <source src="audio/EnglishMP3/<%= @englishAudio %>.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio playback.
           </audio> 
           <a id="audioControl"><img src="/assets/playButton.jpg" width="60" height="60" /></a>

           <img src="/assets/correctAudioAns.png" width="50" height="50" id="draggable"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #CEECF5;">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="audio" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
            <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[0] %></p>
          </div>

          <div id="audio" class="droppable ui-widget-header"">
            <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[1] %></p>
          </div>

          <div id="audio" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
            <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[2] %></p>
          </div>

          <div id="audio" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
            <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[3] %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <% if @index != 9 %>
        <ul class="pager">
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="nextCl3">Next</button>
        </ul>
      <% else %>
        <ul class="pager">
          <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="scorequizCl3">Score Quiz!</button>
        </ul>
      <% end %>

<div id="scoreboard">
  Current score: <br/>
  <%= @score %> out of <%= current_user.bookmark2 %>
</div>
```

Including wordAssociation.js since issues with next button and draggable behavior are both represented in this exercise:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "window", revert: "invalid" });

    $( "#word.droppable" ).droppable({


      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var droppedOn = $(this).find("p").text();
      //alert(droppedOn);   


      $( "#nextCl2" ).click( function() {


       $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'langs',
         dataType: 'script',
         data: {order: droppedOn, option: "next2"}
       });
      });

       $( "#scorequizCl2" ).click( function() {


       $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'langs',
         dataType: 'script',
         data: {order: droppedOn, option: "scorequiz"}
       });
      });

      }

    });
});
```

Word Association html:

```
<h2>Word Association <img src="/assets/informationTip.jpg" alt="Audio association exercise." title="Drag the word given below to its related answer in the blue box" width="35" height="25"></h2>


<div class="well" style="background-color: #D8D8D8; width: 50%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p><%= @englishAssociation %></p>
  </div>     
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #CEECF5;">
      <div class="panel-body">

<div id="word" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[0] %></p>
</div>

<div id="word" class="droppable ui-widget-header"">
  <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[1] %></p>
</div>

<div id="word" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[2] %></p>
</div>

<div id="word" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p><%= @spanishAnswerBank[3] %></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>


  <% if @index != 9 %>
    <ul class="pager">

      <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="nextCl2">Next</button>

    </ul>
  <% else %>
    <ul class="pager">

       <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="scorequizCl2">Score Quiz!</button>


    </ul>
  <% end %>

<div id="scoreboard">
  Current score: <br/>
  <%= @score %> out of <%= current_user.bookmark2 %>
</div>
```

Any thoughts or ideas on why the behavior of the exercises change based on including or excluding the audioControl.js file?

Comment: It sounds like including `audioControls.js` is actually causing a JavasScript error, which would then stops all following Javascript code from running. Can you show the full page rather than the parts you think we want to see?

Comment: I set up a temporary account that I'll delete later on the production website so you can see the full page and described behavior. Website: ninjaspeak.com, username: mtcrts71@gmail.com, password: temp21. audioControls.js is currently commented out in production environment. If you want me to uncomment and push to production let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Your code gives the following error on the Word Association page: `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`. You need to start using debug tools to check for errors in the code.

Comment: What debugger do you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: Although it may seem overkill, the free version of Visual Studio has amazing tools for debugging JavaScript now. Otherwise use the F12 debug tools in the Chrome browser.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about the debug in Chrome browser. Thanks for teaching me how to fish!

Comment: Should anybody come across this in the future the below fixed issue:           window.onload = function(){ 
    // your code 
};